# Java 8 stream join and return multiple values

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, collect

I'm porting a piece of code from .NET to Java and stumbled upon a scenario where I want to use stream to map & reduce.

```
class Content
{
  private String propA, propB, propC;
  Content(String a, String b, String c)
  {
    propA = a; propB = b; propC = c;
  }
  public String getA() { return propA; }
  public String getB() { return propB; }
  public String getC() { return propC; }
}

List<Content> contentList = new ArrayList();
contentList.add(new Content("A1", "B1", "C1"));
contentList.add(new Content("A2", "B2", "C2"));
contentList.add(new Content("A3", "B3", "C3"));
```

I want to write a function that can stream through the contents of contentlist and return a class with result

```
content { propA = "A1, A2, A3", propB = "B1, B2, B3", propC = "C1, C2, C3" }
```

I'm fairly new to Java so you might find some code that resembles more like C# than java

Comment: Good problem description.  But now, what have you tried?  StackOverflow is not a community for getting other people to write code for you.  Rather, you need to post a [mcve] showing what you tried, what you got, and what you expected, and the StackOverflow community might try to help determine where you went wrong and point out solutions.

Comment: @AJNeufeld thanks for the suggestion. This being also the first time me trying to post a question on SO though use it every day. I have it working with a basic for loop with a variable to append the content. And I tried using the forEach on the stream then realized that Java anonymous functions don't allow modifying variable inside the foreach block. Also I contemplated on writing a collect for reach one but realized it wouldnt be efficient either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use proper lambda for [BinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) in reduce function.

```
Content c = contentList
            .stream()
            .reduce((t, u) -> new Content(
                                  t.getA() + ',' + u.getA(),
                                  t.getB() + ',' + u.getB(), 
                                  t.getC() + ',' + u.getC())
                   ).get();
```

Comment: @AJNeufeld agreed, but it's the choice between space & time.

Comment: With only 3 properties, I'm partial to my implementation.  But in a more general case -- with more properties, more complex properties, private properties, etc. -- the best might be `reduce((t, u) -> new Content(t, u);` delegating the merging to the `Content` object itself with a specialized constructor, or actually writing a `ContentCollector` which accumulates the information efficiently.

Answer (score 5):

```
static Content merge(List<Content> list) {
    return new Content(
            list.stream().map(Content::getA).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")),
            list.stream().map(Content::getB).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")),
            list.stream().map(Content::getC).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```

---

EDIT: Expanding on Federico's inline collector, here is a concrete class dedicated to merging Content objects:

```
class Merge {

    public static Collector<Content, ?, Content> collector() {
        return Collector.of(Merge::new, Merge::accept, Merge::combiner, Merge::finisher);
    }

    private StringJoiner a = new StringJoiner(", ");
    private StringJoiner b = new StringJoiner(", ");
    private StringJoiner c = new StringJoiner(", ");

    private void accept(Content content) {
        a.add(content.getA());
        b.add(content.getB());
        c.add(content.getC());
    }

    private Merge combiner(Merge second) {
        a.merge(second.a);
        b.merge(second.b);
        c.merge(second.c);
        return this;
    }

    private Content finisher() {
        return new Content(a.toString(), b.toString(), c.toString());
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
Content merged = contentList.stream().collect(Merge.collector());
```

Answer (score 5):

The most generic way to deal with such tasks would be to combine the result of multiple collectors into a single one.

Using the [jOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) library, you could have the following:

```
Content content = 
    Seq.seq(contentList)
       .collect(
         Collectors.mapping(Content::getA, Collectors.joining(", ")),
         Collectors.mapping(Content::getB, Collectors.joining(", ")),
         Collectors.mapping(Content::getC, Collectors.joining(", "))
       ).map(Content::new);
```

This creates a `Seq` from the input list and combines the 3 given collectors to create a `Tuple3`, which is simply a holder for 3 values. Those 3 values are then mapped into a `Content` using the constructor `new Content(a, b, c)`. The collector themselves are simply mapping each `Content` into its `a`, `b` or `c` value and joining the results together separated with a `", "`.

---

Without third-party help, we could create our own combiner collector like this (this is based of [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) [`pairing`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#pairing-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.BiFunction-) collector, which does the same thing for 2 collectors). It takes 3 collectors as arguments and performs a finisher operation on the result of the 3 collected values.

```
public interface TriFunction<T, U, V, R> {
    R apply(T t, U u, V v);
}

public static <T, A1, A2, A3, R1, R2, R3, R> Collector<T, ?, R> combining(Collector<? super T, A1, R1> c1, Collector<? super T, A2, R2> c2, Collector<? super T, A3, R3> c3, TriFunction<? super R1, ? super R2, ? super R3, ? extends R> finisher) {

    final class Box<A, B, C> {
        A a; B b; C c;
        Box(A a, B b, C c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }
    }

    EnumSet<Characteristics> c = EnumSet.noneOf(Characteristics.class);
    c.addAll(c1.characteristics());
    c.retainAll(c2.characteristics());
    c.retainAll(c3.characteristics());
    c.remove(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH);

    return Collector.of(
            () -> new Box<>(c1.supplier().get(), c2.supplier().get(), c3.supplier().get()),
            (acc, v) -> {
                c1.accumulator().accept(acc.a, v);
                c2.accumulator().accept(acc.b, v);
                c3.accumulator().accept(acc.c, v);
            },
            (acc1, acc2) -> {
                acc1.a = c1.combiner().apply(acc1.a, acc2.a);
                acc1.b = c2.combiner().apply(acc1.b, acc2.b);
                acc1.c = c3.combiner().apply(acc1.c, acc2.c);
                return acc1;
            },
            acc -> finisher.apply(c1.finisher().apply(acc.a), c2.finisher().apply(acc.b), c3.finisher().apply(acc.c)),
            c.toArray(new Characteristics[c.size()])
           );
}
```

and finally use it with

```
Content content = contentList.stream().collect(combining(
    Collectors.mapping(Content::getA, Collectors.joining(", ")),
    Collectors.mapping(Content::getB, Collectors.joining(", ")),
    Collectors.mapping(Content::getC, Collectors.joining(", ")), 
    Content::new
));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to iterate 3 times over the list, or don't want to create too many `Content` intermediate objects, then you'd need to collect the stream with your own implementation:

```
public static Content collectToContent(Stream<Content> stream) {
    return stream.collect(
        Collector.of(
            () -> new StringBuilder[] {
                    new StringBuilder(),
                    new StringBuilder(),
                    new StringBuilder() },
            (StringBuilder[] arr, Content elem) -> {
                arr[0].append(arr[0].length() == 0 ? 
                        elem.getA() : 
                        ", " + elem.getA());
                arr[1].append(arr[1].length() == 0 ? 
                        elem.getB() : 
                        ", " + elem.getB());
                arr[2].append(arr[2].length() == 0 ? 
                        elem.getC() : 
                        ", " + elem.getC());
            },
            (arr1, arr2) -> {
                arr1[0].append(arr1[0].length() == 0 ?
                        arr2[0].toString() :
                        arr2[0].length() == 0 ?
                                "" :
                                ", " + arr2[0].toString());
                arr1[1].append(arr1[1].length() == 0 ?
                        arr2[1].toString() :
                        arr2[1].length() == 0 ?
                                "" :
                                ", " + arr2[1].toString());
                arr1[2].append(arr1[2].length() == 0 ?
                        arr2[2].toString() :
                        arr2[2].length() == 0 ?
                                "" :
                                ", " + arr2[2].toString());
                return arr1;
            },
            arr -> new Content(
                    arr[0].toString(), 
                    arr[1].toString(), 
                    arr[2].toString())));
}
```

This collector first creates an array of 3 empty `StringBuilder` objects. Then defines an accumulator that appends each `Content`element's property to the corresponding `StringBuilder`. Then it defines a merge function that is only used when the stream is processed in parallel, which merges two previously accumulated partial results. Finally, it also defines a finisher function that transforms the 3 `StringBuilder` objects into a new instance of `Content`, with each property corresponding to the accumulated strings of the previous steps.

Please check [`Stream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) javadocs for further reference.